# Finalize class after it is bound to module namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm looking for a way to finalize class creation to recreate `__qualname__` in python pre-3.3. My metaclass `QualNameMeta` recursively sets `__qualname__` and propagates it to members. Due to the way this works, I'd need to execute a function when the class is *added to the module*.

Since functions do not actively participate, I need to test the result to mark unreachable qualnames.

```
class Scope1(object):
    __metaclass__ = QualNameMeta
    def scope_f(self):
        class ScopeF(object):
            __metaclass__ = QualNameMeta
        return ScopeF
    print scope_f.__qualname__ # gives correct Scope1.scope_f
    print scope_f().__qualname__ # gives ScopeF, should be None or Scope1.scope_f.<locals>.ScopeF
```

This test can easily be performed post-creation (excluding unwrapping magic):

```
def test_qualname(obj):
    namespace = sys.modules[obj.__module__]
    for name in obj.__qualname__.split('.'):
        try:
            namespace = getattr(namespace, name)
        except AttributeError:  # name does not point to any object
            return False
    return namespace is obj  # make sure we got the right one
```

However, I cannot get this to work directly from the metaclass. If I call `test_qualname` in `QualMeta.__new__` or `QualMeta.__init__`, the object has *not been bound to the module* yet. So, I need a way to perform the check *after* the object is bound to the module.

Why not decorators?
I need this to work persistently with inheritance, so that an entire class hierarchy can be patched by modifying the baseclass only. Using a metaclass is the only solution I've found so far.

---

A minimal dummy example:

```
class QualMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, class_dict):
        new_cls = type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, class_dict)
        new_cls.__qualname__ = name  # dummy for top-level only
        if not test_qualname(new_cls):  # new_cls is not bound yet, test will fail
            new_cls.__qualname__ = None
        return new_cls


class Qualnamed(object):
    __metaclass__ = QualMeta

print(Qualnamed.__qualname__)  # gives None
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your new attributes in `class_dict`, and let `type.__new__()` do the binding:

```
class QualMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, class_dict):
        class_dict['__qualname__'] = name
        new_cls = type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, class_dict)
        return new_cls

class Qualnamed(object):
    __metaclass__ = QualMeta

print(Qualnamed.__qualname__)  # print "Qualnamed"
```

Comment: The problem isn't binding `__qualname__` to `new_cls`, there'd be an AttributeError otherwise. The problem is that `new_cls` isn't bound to its module at this point. Thus, `new_cls.__qualname__` is defined and valid, but the lookup in its module fails.

Comment: Sorry, read the question to fast. Since the metaclass basically create the class, it is normal that you do not see `QualMeta` inside `modules` or `globals` since it does not exist yet.